# how to do ls on directorty and list number of records per file in single line

Tags: linux, unix

how to do ls -p on directory and list all files with number of records in each in single line command

ex: on running below I am looking for output as

ls -p /abc/def | xargs wc -l

output :
10 file.txt
12 file.txt

Comment: What does `-p` have to do with the question?  If you want to run `wc -l` on all the regular files in the directory, a trailing `/` on directories doesn't seem at all relevant.

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for `command ls | xargs wc -l | tr \\n \\t; echo`, but this is not at all robust. `find -print 0 .... | xargs -0` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following find solution:

```
find /abc/def -type f -exec wc -l '{}' \;
```

Find all files in the /abc/def directory structure and then execute wc -l on each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try only:

```
wc -l * 2> /dev/null
```

That way (2> /dev/null) you suppress *Is a directory* error.